# How to setup two independent sections / parts of the same site in Drupal 8

Tags: drupal, drupal-8

Let's assume my website has independent sections or sub-parts for instance a Poland section and a Ireland section (among others and all tied to the main page). Content editors belong to completely separate groups and they must have some freedom in terms of content organization : their own sub-menus, the ability to add new sub-pages or posts only in their respective part of the site.

I'm used to TYPO3's page tree were each 'branch' can be independent with different user permissions and even different sub-templates. This makes the creation of independent parts within the same site straight forward.

What's the best practice to achieve the same result with Drupal 8 ?

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like your searching for a multi site setup:

- https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/multisite

Where multi site setups in TYPO3 multi site setups are very common, in Drupal people tend to go to independent setups, as you can read in the article "Multisite Drupal 8 considerations"

Comment: Yes, multisite AND a static front page (OP wants them all tied together there).